# Python xml.etree.ElementTree add subelement without console output

Tags: python, elementtree

I want to add a Subelement to a XML file without writing the content to the console.

I am doing the following to add a subelement to a XML file:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree=ET.parse('myfile.XML')
root=tree.getroot()
vpn=ET.SubElement(root,'VPN', attrib={'A': 'VPN1', 'B':'0','C': '0.0001', 'D': '0', 'E': '%'})
ET.dump(root)
```

This does what it should do. But `ET.dump()`is writing the XML content to the console which is problematic for bigger XML structures.

In any case the documentation is a bit weird here. Because on the one hand the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file) (see chapter "Building XML documents")  says that `dump()` should be used to add a sub-element. On the other hand the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementinclude-functions) of  the `dump()` method indicates that this method should only be used for debugging, which explains why content is printed out to the console.

How can I add a XML Subelement without having the content in the console?

Comment: If you don't want to print the xml to the console, then ... don't call `dump()`.  What is the actual problem here?

Comment: If you want to write it to a file instead of display to console, use `root.write('myfile.xml')` instead

Comment: @dinhit I need to add many subelements. So I cannot write to the file and read again the file all the time.

Comment: So use call it when you are done, what is the purpose of `dump()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all your input.
The simple answer is that neither `dump()` not `append()` needs to be called. When writing the file all the Subelements added by the `SubElement` method will be included.
I got confused due to the documentation example and the fact that you cannot access the added SubElements by the `get()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use root.append(vpn) instead of ET.dump(root) this won't write to the console.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree=ET.parse('myfile.XML')
root=tree.getroot()
vpn=ET.SubElement(root,'VPN', attrib={'A': 'VPN1', 'B':'0','C': '0.0001', 'D': '0', 'E': '%'})
# ET.dump(root)
root.append(vpn)
#To dump the data into a file:    
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write('xml_filename.xml')
```